# Removing path and extension from filename in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a series of strings which are full paths to files.  I'd like to save just the filename, without the file extension and the leading path.  So from this:

```
c:\temp\myfile.txt
```

to

```
myfile
```

I'm not actually iterating through a directory, in which case something like PowerShell's `basename` property could be used, but rather I'm dealing with strings alone.

Comment: many answers are not taking in account second part of the question. When Get-Item, Get-ChildItem, or their aliases ls, dir, gi, gci are used, the file from the tested string **must exist**. When we are checking _a series of string_ and not _iterating through a directory_, it must be assumed those files doesn't need to exist on computer where this script will be run.

Answer (score 190):

Way easier than I thought to address the issue of displaying the full path, directory, file name or file extension.

```
                                           ## Output:
$PSCommandPath                             ## C:\Users\user\Documents\code\ps\test.ps1
(Get-Item $PSCommandPath ).Extension       ## .ps1
(Get-Item $PSCommandPath ).Basename        ## test
(Get-Item $PSCommandPath ).Name            ## test.ps1
(Get-Item $PSCommandPath ).DirectoryName   ## C:\Users\user\Documents\code\ps
(Get-Item $PSCommandPath ).FullName        ## C:\Users\user\Documents\code\ps\test.ps1

$ConfigINI = (Get-Item $PSCommandPath ).DirectoryName+"\"+(Get-Item $PSCommandPath ).BaseName+".ini"

$ConfigINI                                 ## C:\Users\user\Documents\code\ps\test.ini
```

Other forms:

```
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
split-path -parent $PSCommandPath
Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
[io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)
```

Comment: It would be nice if beside each example in the top code snippet you showed exactly what text would be returned.

Comment: Example where I don't know the .csr file name, but I know a file exists: `$csr = Get-ChildItem -Path "$($domain.FullName)/*.csr"` then `Write-Host "fileName: $($csr.Basename)"`

Comment: @Leonardo `Get-Item` requires that the file exists, otherwise it throws an error

Comment: @SebMa `$PSCommandPath` returns information of the currently running script, which should be in a saved state before execution.  `Get-Item` in this case should always return a valid value.

Comment: Finally the right answer to how to get the name of the running script _without extension_: `(Get-Item $PSCommandPath ).Basename`.  Thank you!

Comment: Actually, do not answers the question.

Answer (score 158):

There's a handy .NET method for that:

```
C:\PS> [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("c:\temp\myfile.txt")
myfile
```

Comment: This method name is misleading... it seems to get the file name without the extension *or the file path*. That's useful if it's what you want, but a deal-breaker if you only want to remove the extension... which someone finding this method would be led to believe.

Comment: These days, on PowerShell v7, I'd simply use `Split-Path C:\temp\myfile.txt -LeafBase`.

Comment: @KeithHill thanks! -LeafBase was introduced in powershell v6 for anyone else curious

Comment: @TylerH I don't find this method name misleading. Rather, I find it to be quite consistent with [io.path]::GetFileName. I would say that GetFileName is quite clear in its intent and GetFileNameWithoutExtension should do the same thing--without the extension.

Answer (score 73):

Inspired by an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12512709/1811525) of @walid2mi:

```
(Get-Item 'c:\temp\myfile.txt').Basename
```

**Please note:** this only works if the given file *really exists*.

Answer (score 35):

or

```
([io.fileinfo]"c:\temp\myfile.txt").basename
```

or

```
"c:\temp\myfile.txt".split('\.')[-2]
```

Comment: The second example doesn't work too well with something like - "C:\Downloads\ReSharperSetup.7.0.97.60.msi".split('\.')[-2]

Comment: @KeithHill the professional filename does not have dots other than the dot to the extension I gather. But this is to be discussed. If one is generous, one would assume an extension of three characters, so I would `$FileNameWoExt = $FileName.Substring(0, $FileName.Length -4)`

Comment: "one would assume an extension of three characters" is not a good assumption. There are plenty of extensions that use more or less than three characters e.g.: .psd1, .psm1, .json, .docx, .xslx, .pptx, .appx, .appbundle, .cs, .fs, .c, .h, .py, etc.

Comment: first example is important because it allows you to use all the methods from the most upvoted answer when the file doesn't exist

Answer (score 28):

you can use **basename** property

```
PS II> ls *.ps1 | select basename
```

Comment: The OP say: I'm not actually iterating through a directory.

Answer (score 18):

Starting with PowerShell 6, you get the filename without extension like so:

```
split-path c:\temp\myfile.txt -leafBase
```

Comment: This is correct in powershell 6. There is no LeafBase in bog standard 5.1

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have updated the anwer accordingly. What is *bog*?

Comment: Apologies :) where I am from (UK), "Bog Standard" is a slang term for something that is completely ordinary, a "vanilla" version.

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on René Nyffenegger's answer, for those who do not have access to a PowerShell version 6.0, or higher, we use Split Path, which doesn't test for file existence:

```
Split-Path "C:\Folder\SubFolder\myfile.txt" -Leaf
```

This returns "*myfile.txt*". If we know that the file name doesn't have periods in it, we can split the string and take the first part:

```
(Split-Path "C:\Folder\SubFolder\myfile.txt" -Leaf).Split('.') | Select -First 1
```

or

```
(Split-Path "C:\Folder\SubFolder\myfile.txt" -Leaf).Split('.')[0]
```

This returns "*myfile*".
If the file name might include periods, to be safe, we could use the following:

```
$FileName = Split-Path "C:\Folder\SubFolder\myfile.txt.config.txt" -Leaf
$Extension = $FileName.Split('.') | Select -Last 1
$FileNameWoExt = $FileName.Substring(0, $FileName.Length - $Extension.Length - 1)
```

This returns "*myfile.txt.config*".
Here I prefer to use Substring() instead of Replace() because the extension preceded by a period could also be part of the name, as in my example. By using Substring we return the filename without the extension as requested.

Comment: Split-Path is so powerful. Acts as [dirname](/q/63669556), [basename](/q/54305545) and [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path) - only [not on URLs](/q/53766303).

Comment: __for those who do not have access to PowerShell version 6.x, we use Split Path__  [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58628027/641833](René Nyffenegger's answer) indicates that PowerShell 6.0 is required.  Maybe you wrote the wrong thing?

Comment: Thanks @Trisped . I edited the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: It still sounds like those who are on older versions can use `Split-Path`.  Maybe remove the __not__ from the sentence?

Answer (score 8):

[@Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503871/removing-path-and-extension-from-filename-in-powershell#comment16849589_12512709),

here another option:

```
PS II> $f="C:\Downloads\ReSharperSetup.7.0.97.60.msi"

PS II> $f.split('\')[-1] -replace '\.\w+$'

PS II> $f.Substring(0,$f.LastIndexOf('.')).split('\')[-1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Given any arbitrary path string, various static methods on the System.IO.Path object give the following results.

```
strTestPath                 = C:\Users\DAG\Documents\Articles_2018\NTFS_File_Times_in_CMD\PathStringInfo.ps1
GetDirectoryName            = C:\Users\DAG\Documents\Articles_2018\NTFS_File_Times_in_CMD
GetFileName                 = PathStringInfo.ps1
GetExtension                = .ps1
GetFileNameWithoutExtension = PathStringInfo
```

Following is the code that generated the above output.

```
[console]::Writeline( "strTestPath                 = {0}{1}" ,
                      $strTestPath , [Environment]::NewLine );
[console]::Writeline( "GetDirectoryName            = {0}" ,
                      [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName( $strTestPath ) );
[console]::Writeline( "GetFileName                 = {0}" ,
                      [IO.Path]::GetFileName( $strTestPath ) );
[console]::Writeline( "GetExtension                = {0}" ,
                      [IO.Path]::GetExtension( $strTestPath ) );
[console]::Writeline( "GetFileNameWithoutExtension = {0}" ,
                      [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension( $strTestPath ) );
```

Writing and testing the script that generated the above uncovered some quirks about how PowerShell differs from C#, C, C++, the Windows NT command scripting language, and just about everything else with which I have any experience.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one without parentheses

```sh
[io.fileinfo] 'c:\temp\myfile.txt' | % basename
```

Answer (score 3):

This script searches in a folder and sub folders and rename files by removing their extension

```bsh
    Get-ChildItem -Path "C:/" -Recurse -Filter *.wctc |

    Foreach-Object {

      rename-item $_.fullname -newname $_.basename

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by splitting the string a couple of times.

```
#Path
$Link = "http://some.url/some/path/file.name"

#Split path on "/"
#Results of split will look like this : 
# http:
#
# some.url
# some
# path
# file.name
$Split = $Link.Split("/")

#Count how many Split strings there are
#There are 6 strings that have been split in my example
$SplitCount = $Split.Count

#Select the last string
#Result of this selection : 
# file.name
$FilenameWithExtension = $Split[$SplitCount -1]

#Split filename on "."
#Result of this split : 
# file
# name
$FilenameWithExtensionSplit = $FilenameWithExtension.Split(".")

#Select the first half
#Result of this selection : 
# file
$FilenameWithoutExtension = $FilenameWithExtensionSplit[0]

#The filename without extension is in this variable now
# file
$FilenameWithoutExtension
```

Here is the code without comments :

```
$Link = "http://some.url/some/path/file.name"
$Split = $Link.Split("/")
$SplitCount = $Split.Count
$FilenameWithExtension = $Split[$SplitCount -1]
$FilenameWithExtensionSplit = $FilenameWithExtension.Split(".")
$FilenameWithoutExtension = $FilenameWithExtensionSplit[0]
$FilenameWithoutExtension
```

Comment: Why so hard way?

Comment: Doesn't work if the filename contains more than one period, e.g. MyApp.exe.config

Answer (score 2):

The command below will store in a variable all the file in your folder, matchting the extension ".txt":

```
$allfiles=Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\*" -Include *.txt
foreach ($file in $allfiles) {
    Write-Host $file
    Write-Host $file.name
    Write-Host $file.basename
}
```

`$file` gives the file with path, name and extension: c:\temp\myfile.txt

`$file.name` gives file name & extension: myfile.txt

`$file.basename` gives only filename: myfile

Comment: OK, but the question is about filenames (strings), not actual files.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me! Btw the question doesn't specify strings in title and someone coming for a search engine will end up here.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple PowerShell 5.1 one-liner options that puts the path at the start of the line.

```
'c:\temp\myfile.txt' | Split-Path -Leaf
```

OR

```
'c:\temp\myfile.txt' -as [IO.FileInfo] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName
```

Comment: @MUYBelgium Might be related to my use of `%` as an alias for ForEach-Object, that can fail on some setups. Anyway, I was very new to PowerShell at the time. I've now updated the answer with better options, so hopefully the new code works for you.