# What is the cut equivalent command in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to cut specific content from a string and store it in a variable to use later.

The string is :

```
\\path\shares\Product\Product_Name\Custom\Version\Version_1\Packages\2018-05-31_07-33-12\PRODUCT_NAME_1_SETUP.exe
```

How can I cut the part in caps(`PRODUCT_NAME_1_SETUP`) and store it in variable in powershell.

I'd really appreciate help.

The path is actually stored in a variable called path_name, and I'm trying the following:

$build_name=[io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension('$($path_name)')

But it is not working. I'm getting O/P "$path_name" only. :(

Even $build_name=(Get-Item '$($path_name)').Basename is failing too.

Comment: [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($p)

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Having given you the boilerplate, I will also suggest that you look at the [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-6) cmdlet and [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6) if you want a "pure PowerShell" solution, or follow the suggestion from @Tomek if direct .NET calls are acceptable.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - My first instinct was also Split-Path, but it does not support trimming file extension. Splitting by '.' is not good also as . is valid character in file name and extension does not have to be exactly 3 chars so trimming last 4 characters would not work either. Y'd need to split by '.'  , remove last string, put it back together.

Comment: @John_J 
`$build_name=[io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($path_name)`
if You do single quotes (') You tell powershell not to evaluate variable inside. just ditch the single quotes.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @Tomek.  Your only problem here is your usage of single quotes which are never evaluated for embedded variables or subexpressions.  See [`Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Thank you very much for helping! This is working perfectly. :)

Answer (score 2):

If You need to select only file name from a Path - best way is to use 
    `[io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`
It was already answered here:
[Removing path and extension from filename in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503871/removing-path-and-extension-from-filename-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Two variants using a RegEx

```
$String ="\\path\shares\Product\Product_Name\Custom\Version\Version_1\Packages\2018-05-31_07-33-12\PRODUCT_NAME_1_SETUP.exe"
$string -match "([^\\]+)\.exe$"|out-Null
$matches[1]

sls -input $string -patt "([^\\]+)\.exe$"|%{$_.Matches.groups[1].Value}
```

---

Explaining the RegEx:

```
([^\\]+)\.exe$
 1st Capturing Group ([^\\]+)
 Match a single character not present in the list below [^\\]+
 + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, 
   as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
 \\ matches the character \ literally (case sensitive)
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
exe matches the characters exe literally (case sensitive)
$ asserts position at the end of the string, 
  or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)
```